# What is the difference between t1.current thread and thread.currentThread?

Tags: java

this is a coding question for Java language.

May I know what is the difference between Option A and B?

```
Thread T1; 
Option A: t1.currentThread();
Option B: t1 = Thread.currentThread();
```

The compiler gives an error for Option A.

Comment: Diff between 2 options where 1 does not compile ?^^

Answer (score 0):

> May I know what is the difference between Option A and B?

One thing different ways.

> The compiler gives an error for Option A.

Compiler shows error `Variable 'threa' might not have been initialize`. because you did not initialize `Thread t1`. Try below code for better understanding.

```
        Thread threa = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your thread work
                }
            });
            threa.start();
            threa.currentThread();
```

Now you can see in **[Thread Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)**. `currentThread` method in `Thread` class is **`static`**.

> Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.

If you call `Thread.currentThread()` that is **right way** to call static method. If you call `t1.currentThread();`, then it is **redundant** to call static method from an instance/object.

So above code is redundant, you can call it via **`Thread class`**.

```
Thread.currentThread();
```

Comment: If the compiler failed to compile the program, then a NullPointerException could not possibly have been thrown. Also, calling a static method through a reference value that is null does not do that.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I made answer clearer.